# Give an example where a module M is not free but its submodule N is free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have following question.

> Give examples where for a non free R-module $M$ it's submodule $N$ is free. Is $M/N$ always free?

I have a problem with modules and I really don't understand them fundamentally.
I know cases where we have a free module and have to find a non free submodule, but the other way around i can't come up with anything. I thought about taking an element in $M$ and the generated submodule created from powers of this element would be free(this was a way to create an abelian group in a non abelian group, and i thought it might work the same), but I am not quite sure. Also, what about the factor module. If you see a factor module and the question is if it is free or not, what would you do?

I have an exam coming up very soon and questions like this will come for sure, so I would really need some hints, help or insight.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you know the structure theorem which gives an easy way to generate modules? This provides a splitting (decomposition) of a module into free and torsion parts.

Comment: Or even otherwise, do you know how to take the direct sum of modules? What happens when you take a direct sum of a free and non-free module?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know anything about the direct sum of modules. Regarding the first question, we only had an example in $\mathbb{Z}$ where if we take Zk=ℤ/kZ  then we can take cartesian products: Zk1×...×Zkm×Z^r and we name  the part Zk1,...,Zkm the torsion part and the Z^r the free part. But that's the only example and theory about it. Also for free modules the theory was also incredibly vague, only defining them as modules with a basis and the fact that all free ones have to be isomorphic to $R^n$. So that's all the theory i have available for this type of questions.

Comment: Even with that information you're good! So try $M = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. What is the free part, what is the torsion part? Is $M$ free? Is the free part free (sounds stupid but just a guiding question :) )? This should answer your question

Comment: I guess the free part is Z and the torsion part is Z/2? If the free part is Z, then yes Z is free? And I am not quite sure about M, I don't think it's free, maybe it would be free if we had prime numbers for example $M=\mathbb{Z/3}\times\mathbb{Z/2}$?

Comment: You said that all free ones are isomorphic to $R^n$ so $M$ is not free because it's not of the form $R^n$!

Comment: Oh right, okay I see. But now I would have one more questions. Would $M$ in the example you gave be an abelian group? And would it have anything to do with the free modules?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126892/discussion-between-katrin-and-osama-ghani).